# Firestore v9 - Get nested collection based of string being found in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a practice chat app here. Been a couple years since using Firestore the last time.

I'm using v9 and having trouble getting this nested "messages" collection if the "users" array in the document contains a specific ID. I am easily able to return the users array itself just fine or the doc ID, just can't seem to find something in the official docs or elsewhere that will also return the collection.

Here is an image of my Firestore setup below:

[image: Image link to show Firestore DB structure]

```
export const getConversations = async (userID) => {
    const messagesQ = query(collectionGroup(db, 'conversations'), where('users', 'array-contains', userID))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(messagesQ)
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
    })
}
```

The code snippet above is the best I can seem to come up with, but like I said, it obviously only returns the users array itself. Not the messages collection.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/yo5ink/get_nested_collection_based_of_string_in_users/

Comment: Yea, I was getting desperate to figure this one out. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current structure, the best you can do is loop over the results you currently get, and access the `messages` subcollection for each of them.

If you want to retrieve documents from the `messages` collection you'll have to ensure those documents contain the same `users` information that you have in the `conversations` document now. With that you can then do a collection group query on `messages` instead of `conversations`.

---

To get a reference to the subcollection of the `conversations` results:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const messagesRef = collection(doc.ref, "messages");
})
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So I think the issue I'm having is how do I now loop over the results I get to access the messages subcollection? I seem to be failing hard on the syntax here.

Thanks for the post edit to show the image, btw. Was going to be difficult to ask without being able to properly show the image!

Comment: I added an example of how to get a reference to the subcollection. For things like this, I find it handy to keep the reference docs open: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot

Comment: Thanks so much. This got me to where I needed!